# 'React/RCTAnimationType.h' file not found in ios react native

Tags: react-native, zendesk

After integrating "react-native-zendesk-support" ti my ios project and followed all the giver steps i got an error while building ios app

> 'React/RCTAnimationType.h' file not found
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If95D.png)

Comment: Welcome @Hari Krishnani on StackOverflow, It would be really helpful to others if you can mention what are the steps you have followed. For more help please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @Hari Krishnani Could you able to share your Podfile in here

Comment: And also what is the module which you used for zendesk-support ?

Comment: Hi @EL173, I cant add my pod file here, its saying to long to add..

Well i have used "react-native-zendesk-support" ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-zendesk-support ) this module. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Hari what is the version of react-native-zendesk-support ?

Comment: @EL173 here is it.  

      "react-native-zendesk-support": "^1.0.9",

Comment: Hi @Rajan, Sorry i didn't saw your comment.

Here are those steps i followed..

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-zendesk-support